# Update array value in yq on base of criteria

Tags: yaml, yq

I have sample yaml like below

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'snmp-moxa'
  static_configs:
  - targets:
- job_name: prometheus
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - localhost:9090
```

I want to add IP address where job_name is equal to 'snmp-moxa', I tried following but none working

To verify it reaches at correct path

```
# yq eval '.scrape_configs[] | select(.job_name == "snmp-moxa") | .static_configs' prom.yaml
- targets:
```

Following are two tries to update values

```
#yq eval -i '.scrape_configs[] | select(.job_name == "snmp-moxa") | .static_configs.targets |= . + ["10.11.158.177"]' prom.yaml
Error: Cannot index array with 'targets' (strconv.ParseInt: parsing "targets": invalid syntax)


# yq eval -i '.scrape_configs[] | select(.job_name == "snmp-moxa") | .static_configs.targets |= . + [10.11.158.177]' prom.yaml
Error: expected end of expression but found '|', please check expression syntax
```

Resulting yaml should be like

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'snmp-moxa'
  static_configs:
  - targets: 10.11.158.177  
or
  - targets: 
    - 10.11.158.177 
- job_name: prometheus
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - localhost:9090
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea is almost right, but the `static_configs` record is an *array* type and not a scalar type. So you need to access the sub-fields inside it, with the `[]` notation, i.e.

You probably need the `targets` as an array so use the `+=` to append the array content (tested on yq version 4.13.5)

```
yq e '(.scrape_configs[] | select(.job_name == "snmp-moxa").static_configs[].targets) += [ "10.11.158.177" ]' yaml
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, documentation miss of this kind of tips !